# How to store dictionary in redis from python

Tags: python, redis

I'm trying to store a python dict in memory through redis, I was following the [pypi doc](https://pypi.org/project/redis/), when I try to instance RedisCluster i got this error:

```
from redis.cluster import RedisCluster as Redis # this line works
rc = Redis(host='localhost', port=6379) # here is the problem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/redisTesting/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/cluster.py", line 1306, in initialize
    raise RedisClusterException(
redis.exceptions.RedisClusterException: Cluster mode is not enabled on this node
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/redisTesting/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/cluster.py", line 507, in __init__
    self.nodes_manager = NodesManager(
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/redisTesting/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/cluster.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self.initialize()
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/redisTesting/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/cluster.py", line 1334, in initialize
    raise RedisClusterException(
redis.exceptions.RedisClusterException: ERROR sending "cluster slots" command to redis server 127.0.0.1:6379. error: Cluster mode is not enabled on this node
```

I know that the problem is `Cluster mode is not enabled on this node` but I didn't find a way to solve this error, how can enable the cluster mode on the node?

Also I find a way to store this dict in memory with

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis()
r.hmset({
    "color": "green",
    "price": 99.99,
    "style": "baseball",
    "quantity": 200,
    "npurchased": 0,
})
```

but this got me a deprecate warning `<input>:1: DeprecationWarning: Redis.hmset() is deprecated. Use Redis.hset() instead.` and when I tryed to use r.hset() the terminal got me `redis.exceptions.DataError: Invalid input of type: 'dict'. Convert to a bytes, string, int or float first.`

Comment: Please decide about which one of the two problems you want to ask. There should be only one question per post.

Comment: If you don't have a cluster, then you should just run `from redis import Redis`

Comment: Check out `pickle.dumps()` and/or `json.dumps()` perhaps with `.encode("utf-8")` on your dictionary.

Comment: The `hset` command can be called in one of two ways:  Either `r.hset(name, key, value)` or `r.hset(name, mapping=<dictionary>)`.  You need to adding `mapping=` to your `hset` command.

Comment: the question is: how can I enable the cluster mode on the node? the rest is aditional info about what I already did

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, `hmset` is deprecated.
Instead you should use `hset` which has the ability to receive dictionary as an input using the `mapping` argument (as long as it is not nested).

Another observation is that you are missing the mapping key name while calling hset.
so this should work:

```
r.hmset("you_key_name", {
  "color": "green",
  "price": 99.99,
  "style": "baseball",
  "quantity": 200,
  "npurchased": 0,
})
```

If you need nested abilities, then add in json dumps like so:

```
r.hmset("you_key_name", {
  "color": "green",
  "price_json": json.dumps({"val":99.99, "currency": "$"})
  "style": "baseball",
  "quantity": 200,
  "npurchased": 0,
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Change redis.cluster to redis and connection would succeed.

```
#from redis.cluster import RedisCluster as Redis # this line works (but assumes you are connecting to Redis Cluster)
from redis import Redis
rc = Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)
```